# Can not block OVER_QUERY_LIMIT

Tags: javascript, api, google-maps, google-api

I try to get driving road and I have problem with OVER_QUERY_LIMIT. I saw similar problems in oter topics but it still haven 't resolve my problem. Below I present code and I will be greatful for tips. Thanks

```
function initMap(startLat, startLng, endLat, endLng) {
        var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService;
        var directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer;
        var start = new google.maps.LatLng(startLat, startLng);
        var end = new google.maps.LatLng(endLat, endLng);
        calculateAndDisplayRoute(start, end, directionsService, directionsDisplay);
    }
    var i;
    var j;
    var delay;
    function calculateAndDisplayRoute(start, end, directionsService, directionsDisplay) {
        directionsService.route({
            origin: start,
            destination: end,
            travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING
        }, function(response, status) {
            if (status === google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
                var totaldistance = 0;
                var route = response.routes[0];
                // display total distance information.
                for (var i = 0; i < route.legs.length; i++) {
                    totaldistance = totaldistance + route.legs[i].distance.value;
                }
                document.getElementById('distance').innerHTML += "<p>total distance is " + (totaldistance / 1000).toFixed(2) + " km</p>";
                directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
            } else {
                if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OVER_QUERY_LIMIT)
                    j -= 2;
                else
                    alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
            }
        })
        ;
    }
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initMap);
    function addMarker(lat,lon,optionMarker)
    {
        optionMarker.position = new google.maps.LatLng(lat,lon);
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker(optionMarker);
    }

    function mapStart()
    {
        var optionMap =
            {
                center: new google.maps.LatLng(50.27191 ,18.86805),
                zoom: 10,
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            }
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), optionMap);
        for(i=0; i < points.length; i += 2)
        {
            addMarker(points[i],points[i+1],{});
            for(j = i+2; j < points.length; j += 2 ) {
                initMap(points[i], points[i + 1], points[j], points[j + 1]);
            }
        }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Apparently you are hitting a per session limit of directions service of Maps JavaScript API.

> Service requests are rate-limited per user session, regardless of how many users share the same project. When you first load the service API, you are allocated an initial quota of requests. Once you use this quota, the API enforces rate limits on additional requests on a per-second basis. If too many requests are made within a certain time period, the API returns an OVER_QUERY_LIMIT response code. The per-session rate limit prevents the use of client-side services for batch requests.

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/usage

You loop repeatedly through points making directions requests to Google's servers. This looping behavior can overload the session between your client and Google.

You should retry with increasing delays between attempts with OVER_QUERY_LIMIT status. Usually the delay is increased by a multiplicative factor with each attempt, an approach known as Exponential Backoff (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_backoff).